# Accidentally restored iPhone, how can I recover my data?

Tags: iphone, itunes, restore

I connected my current iPhone to iTunes and I accidentally hit restore and now my iPhone is set up like my old iPhone 4! Is there a way to make my iPhone back to the way it was an hour ago?

Comment: Did you ever make a backup of your current phone, either via iTunes or via iCloud?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a backup of your data, either in iTunes, on iCloud, or otherwise, you can't restore your data. If you do have a backup, you should restore it per the method for the specific backup medium.